# System.Windows.Forms in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to implement a website screen shot class as described here http://www.plentyofcode.com/2007/09/website-screenshot-capture-with-aspnet.html

The class imports the following methods

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Diagnostics

Namespace GetSiteThumbnail

   Public Class GetImage [...]
```

The reference to System.Windows.Forms apparently worked in asp.net 2.0 but has been removed from 3/3.5  is there an equivalent for 3.5 or does anyone know a way to replicate this website screen shot setup in 3.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

can you just add the references to the System.Windows.Forms dll ?

Answer (score 1):

Your project needs a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly. Make sure it is there.

Answer (score 1):

For refrence to anyone looking at this later.  By adding

```
<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

To the `<assemblies>` section of your web.config file you can use System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Gah, you made me cringe there. You shouldn't use the Forms assembly in a ASP.Net website.

Comment: It's only to get a screenshot of another website... If you've got another idea I'd love to hear it